# Тихая установка MySQL

Tags: mysql

Такой вопрос: можно ли установить MySQL со своими преднастройками (например пароль root) или использовать какой-нить инсталлятор, в котором можно эти настройки прописать?

Comment: А куда установить-то? Если linux - написАть bash-скрипт, если windows - vbs, например...

Comment: Пока Windows, но в планах и Ubuntu. Есть ли какие уроки, как написать этот скрипт или где начать копать?

Comment: Хм, это случайно не то, что Вы ищите: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/windows-installer-msi-quiet.html ?

Comment: Да, что-то близко. Буду разбираться.